# Wrong email given when trying to update apps

Tags: ios, itunes, email, iphone

When trying to update my whatsapp version, the email that is provided when required to input my password is incorrect? I am also unable to change it my correct email??

Comment: The app belongs to whoever 'bought' it from the iTunes store [even if it was free] & can only be updated by using that account's credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the app was bought using a different iTunes account. You can display the buyer informations on your Mac using iTunes:

1. Open iTunes
2. Navigate to the "Apps" section/tab in the horizintal navigation menu
3. Search for "WhatsApp" and select it
4. Hit `⌘ + I` or right click and select "Information"
5. Click on the "File" tab for the buyer information